# how to pass dynamic data from parent to child in angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular6

As we know , in angular parent to child communication happened using @Input decorator but how to pass dynamic data from parent to child.for example 'name' property is defined in parent and it's value changes dynamically and updated value of 'name' we are going to using in child component so how to achieve it without services.

Comment: please share code

Comment: you can achieve that using ngrx or angular-redux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can watch your input changes in the child component with ngOnChanges lifecycle

in your child component you should `implements OnChanges`

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let change = changes[propName];
      if (propName === "YOUR_INPUT_NAME") {
        this.YOUR_INPUT_NAME = (change.currentValue);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Isn't the question about passing data from parent to children, not vice versa?

Comment: thanks for explanation but question is about passing dynamic data from parent to child

Answer (score 0):

You can make the use of service to get the updated value in child when it gets changed in parent.

For that you need to declare the variable in the service of type observable.
your **myService.service.ts** would be having the following code:

```
@Injectable()
export class myService {
myInput:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)
 }
```

now from your parent component change the value of this myInput by using:

```
myServie.myInput.next(true)
```

and subscribe this variable in your child component by using:

```
 myService.myInput.subscribe((data)=>{console.log(data)})
```

In both the parent and child component add the line `private mySerivce:MyService` in the arguments of constructor.